# How to make Angular ng-grid cell editable via binding?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Just starting out with ng-grid.  I need to make individual cells (i.e. for a given row and column) editable based on the boolean value of a property in my grid array.  It would be great if I could simply bind to the array property to turn on (or off) cell editing.  However, I don't see this option available.  Did I overlook something, does ng-grid support this out of the box?  If not, any suggestions as to how I could implement this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with something like that out of the box.

I would create a cell template for each cell and put there two divs - one div for viewing and one div for editing, and then add ng-show to each and bind it to the boolean property that indicates whether the cell is editable or not.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FP7Jt/

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +     
   '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.age"/></div></div>'}
```